# Qfield package sync crashes QGIS when creating for Qfield

Tags: qgis, qfield, qfieldsync

I am trying to create a package for Qfield but when I do, it crashes QGIS. I've tried to fix some suggestions it gives, like changing a layer to UTF - 8, but it seems to stall on other layers and then crashes.

I've updated Qfield sync, and have QGIS 3.16 on Windows 10. I'm trying to update QGIS but have to do it by hotspot and it's saying 8 hours..

It gives me the report below.

Can anyone help solve problem so I can package project for Qfield?

```
Crash ID: 1bd3202f377fff722e7a82156a78f30fd22fbfb2

Stack Trace
QMetaObject::disconnect :
QObject::disconnectImpl :
QgsTerrainDownloader::tileImageToHeightMap :
QgsPhongTexturedMaterialSettings::diffuseTexturePath :
QMetaObject::activate :
Qgs3DMapSettings::setTerrainLayers :
Qgs3DMapCanvasDockWidget::onMainCanvasLayersChanged :
QMetaObject::activate :
QgsMapCanvas::setLayersPrivate :
QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge::setCanvasLayers :
QgisApp::readProject :
QMetaObject::activate :
QgsProject::readProject :
QgsProject::readProjectFile :
QgsProject::read :
QgsProject::read :
PyInit__core :
PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords :
PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords :
PyEval_EvalFrameDefault :
PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords :
PyEval_EvalFrameDefault :
PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords :
PyEval_EvalFrameDefault :
PyFunction_FastCallDict :
PyMethodDef_RawFastCallDict :
PyObject_Call :
PyInit_QtCore :
PyInit_QtCore :
PyInit_QtCore :
PyInit_QtCore :
PyInit_QtCore :
QMetaObject::activate :
QAbstractButton::clicked :
QAbstractButton::click :
QAbstractButton::mouseReleaseEvent :
QWidget::event :
QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper :
QApplication::notify :
QgsApplication::notify :
QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2 :
QApplicationPrivate::sendMouseEvent :
QSizePolicy::QSizePolicy :
QSizePolicy::QSizePolicy :
QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper :
QApplication::notify :
QgsApplication::notify :
QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2 :
QGuiApplicationPrivate::processMouseEvent :
QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents :
QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents :
UserCallWinProcCheckWow :
DispatchMessageWorker :
QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents :
qt_plugin_query_metadata :
QEventLoop::exec :
QCoreApplication::exec :
main :
BaseThreadInitThunk :
RtlUserThreadStart :




QGIS Info
QGIS Version: 3.16.7-Hannover
QGIS code revision: 0471743889
Compiled against Qt: 5.11.2
Running against Qt: 5.11.2
Compiled against GDAL: 3.1.4
Running against GDAL: 3.1.4



System Info
CPU Type: x86_64
Kernel Type: winnt
Kernel Version: 10.0.18362
```